# How secure would making my own login system in React/NodeJS Be?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, authentication

I'm currently thinking of adding a login system for a website, but I'm a bit hesitant on doing it because of a few security flaws I'm not sure how to solve:

- How would you prevent someone from making a script that spams registries for new accounts?
- Would spam logging in / out stress the DB(mysql) if someone wanted to try to slow down the website?
- Is it recommended to even make my own login system?

My main concern is basically how to prevent malicious bad actors from trying to slow down the website, although I know there are other things I should be looking to prevent.
Any insights/best practices are welcome ,as a scavenge of the web didn't lead me to any super useful resources on these topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is it recommended to even make my own login system?"

**No.**

You'll want to use software with community support, and more importantly, a large installed base so that if/when there's a security problem you're unlikely to be the first victim. Ideally it's a popular enough system that a [CVE](https://cve.mitre.org) is issued, and all you need to do is follow the recommendations for patching/updating.

There's a lot more to a login system than verifying passwords. You've touched on a few concerns here, but there are a lot more. Security is complex and multi-faceted.

The good news is in Node there's a lot of options that meet that criteria. Personally I've used [Passport](https://www.passportjs.org) which has a large library of add-ons making it quite capable, but there are [many others](https://openbase.com/categories/js/best-nodejs-authentication-libraries).